# iphone ios sample ffplay main.c --> FFmpeg.c change and input parameter , following errer please advice

Tags: iphone, ffmpeg, filepath

FFmpeg main c source

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int flags, i;
    argv[1] = "-i";
    argv[2] = "ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=1218551163727305907";    
         //argv[2] = "mon.mp3";

    argv[3] = "-acodec";
    argv[4] = "libfaac";
    argv[5] = "-ac";
    argv[6] = "2";
    argv[7] = "-ar";
    argv[8] = "44100";
    argv[9] = "-ab";
    argv[10] = "128k";
    argv[11] = "output.aac";
    argv[3] = "-vn";
    argv[4] = "-acodec";
    argv[5] = "libfaac";
    argv[6] = "-ac";
    argv[7] = "2";
    argv[8] = "-ar";
    argv[9] = "44100";
    argv[10] = "-ab";
    argv[11] = "128k";
    argv[12] = "output.aac";
    //  argv[14] = "rtsp://video.bouygtel.fr/50400/tf1.sdp";
    argc += 12;
```

error : ipod-library://item/item.mp3?id=1218551163727305907: No such file or directory
and if 
argv[2] = "mon.mp3"; ---> mon.mp3: No such file or directory

please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the full path for the file. If it is in your resources, it would be something like: `[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mon" ofType:@"mp3"];`

Regards,
Alexandre